# How to create multiple add_callback in tornado?

Tags: python, tornado, addcallback

I'm trying to add multiple callbacks in tornado main loop. But when I run this code:

```
def task(num):
    print 'task %s' % num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1,5):
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda: task(num=i))
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I get output 5 times: 'task 5', not task 1.. task 5.
When I change **main** like that:

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda: task(1))
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda: task(2))
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda: task(3))
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda: task(4))
```

everything works fine (I get task1-task5 in output). What am I doing wrong in the first case?

Comment: the lambda closure is built on `i` and it ends up as 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is the same problem like in JS?
look at this answer: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

"the problem is that the variable i, within each of your anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the function."

try simple test:

```
def task(num):
    print 'task %s' % num

def create_task(num):
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda: task(num))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1,5):
        create_task(i)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. The simpliest way to fix is: tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda i=i: task(i))

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your lambda into **functools.partial()** function which solves "pointer issue"

`IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=functools.partial(task, i*10))`

**tl;dr;**

Here is an example with the "pointer issue" BUG:

```
def task(num):
    print(num)

for i in range(1, 6):
    print ("poop {0}".format(i))
    IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda: task(i))
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

at the code example above `i` will be a memory pointer to the value `range()` currently iterating on. It is changing from 1 to 2 then to 3, 4, 5.

Tornado's add_callback() asynchronous function returns control to the main program immediately making all the 5 calls to `task()` function execute almost at the same time. And at this point `i` is already got the value of `5`.

To solve this issue quickly use `funtools.partial` function instead of lambda and research the difference ;)

Here is BUG-free example:

```
IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=functools.partial(task, i*10))
```